# Do I need to downgrade my Xperia J to ICS before installing a custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, downgrade

I would like to install a Custom ROM in my Xperia J and its named [AVD ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2309415). To install that ROM do I have to install the ICS first or no need?

Please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is rooted/unlocked, and you already use a custom recovery (like [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) or [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp)), there's no need to downgrade first. [flashing](/questions/tagged/flashing) the [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom) will either replace the complete system, regardless of the installed version: usually, the images contain complete "disk images" for all relevant partitions.

If, on the other hand, your device is *not* rooted, and there doesn't exist any [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) solution for the currently installed Android version, but only for ICS: then yes, you might need to downgrade so you can gain [root](/questions/tagged/root) access to your device, and flash a custom [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery).

On some devices it might be sufficient to simply unlock the bootloader in order to install a custom recovery or flash a custom rom. If that applies to your device, I must leave for someone else to answer.

Comment: May I keep the stock kernel or must have to install new kernel ?

Comment: The kernel is part of the image, so you won't keep it either: the custom ROM will bring its own.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary...

No need to downgrade...